# Does Linux clone() create a new thread for the child?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have a C program that uses fork-execv to create a child process to run a Python program.  I want the parent and child processes to communicate through IPC (for example, FIFOs) and the child process will continue running for the duration of the parent process, performing Python functions for the parent at intervals signalled through IPC.

My problem is that once the child process starts it prevents the C program from running, so there is no opportunity for the two to interact.  The C program is created on the main thread, not with a new thread created with pthreads.

It looks like the solution is to use clone() instead of fork(), which is also helpful because I want the two programs to share the same heap, which I can't do with fork().

The Python child process runs in a while True loop to keep it running while the parent process proceeds.  Here is a very simplified version for the purpose of illustration (without IPC):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 
import os 
import time

a = 0   

while True:
    a = a + 1
    if a > 50000:
        a = 0
    time.sleep(1)
```

The C program for fork-execv:

```
#include <sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* for wait */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int call_PyFn(int64_t fdx)
{
    //Create buffer for file descriptor
    int buflen = (int)((ceil(log10(fdx))+1)*sizeof(char));
    char fdbuf[buflen];
    sprintf(fdbuf, "%d", (int)fdx);
    int status;
    char * paramsList[] = {
        "/usr/bin/python3",
            "-m",
            "NLTK_Python_Libs",
            "-c",
            fdbuf,
            (char *)NULL };

    if ( fork() == 0 ){
        printf("I am the child\n");
        execv(paramsList[0],paramsList); }
    else {
        printf("I am the parent\n");
        wait( &status ); }

    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Will clone() run the child process on a separate thread?
2. When I do multithreading work I use pthread_setaffinity to pin each thread to a specific core.  Can I do that with clone()?  From the docs, "If CLONE_THREAD is set, the child is placed in the same thread group as the calling process" but "without specifying CLONE_THREAD, then the resulting thread is placed in a new thread group whose TGID is the same as the thread's TID."  https://linux.die.net/man/2/clone.  That doesn't completely answer this question re affinity.  Ideally I would like the two processes to run on the same core so that if I use this in a multicore project I can have each core run its own cloned process on the second thread of the parent's core.

I've read a lot of information on this but nothing completely clears it up for me.  In the scenario described, am I right that fork does not create a new thread, which results in the child process blocking the parent, whereas clone will create a new thread?

It looks like the answer is yes, but confirmation would help.  The question at [How to create a real thread with clone() on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858207/how-to-create-a-real-thread-with-clone-on-linux) comes close, but doesn't clear up all my questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the C code? With `fork`

Comment: I'll post it above.

Comment: *My problem is that once the child process starts it prevents the C program from running, so there is no opportunity for the two to interact.* - how do you expect them to interact if the parent is starting to `wait` for the child to terminate right after it was spawned? This is a textbook example of an XY-problem.

Comment: I'm new to fork-execv -- I thought that was necessary in all cases.  I'd still like to know if I use clone() can I pin affinity?  And thanks for your comment about wait.

Comment: The parent process should enter some kind of message listening loop, and should `wait` for the child only after everything is done and the child is expected to terminate (in your case it's never in fact..)

Comment: Generally speaking, do not use `clone()`.  It should be considered an expert-only API for use in those rare situations that are not adequately supported by either standard multithreading or standard multiprocessing.  It's also Linux-specific, so it's not a viable option if you want broader portability.

Comment: There is no termination shown in the code above, but at end of parent it will send a code via IPC for the child to terminate.

Comment: So you see, you have a deadlock situation here. The parent cannot send the termination signal, because it is waiting for the child to terminate.

Comment: @John Bollinger - with fork-execv, will it run in a separate thread pinned to the same core, or does it run on the main thread along with the parent?

Comment: Let's clear the terminology. `fork` is spawning a new *process*. Threads are something else (even though on he lower level they might be the same)

Comment: Then I suspect that means I should not worry about thread affinity.

Comment: @RTC222, fork / execv starts a new, separate process (initially with a single thread).  In fact, just the `fork()` part does that.  You don't necessarily need to follow it up with an exec.

Comment: Thank you both.  That helps a lot.

Comment: @EugeneSh - You said above that the parent should wait for the child to terminate.  Can they run concurrently and terminate at the same time?

Comment: @RTC222 They do execute concurrently, but the parent should `wait` for it even if the child terminated before, otherwise it will remain "zombie".

Comment: So my IPC between the two is viable -- the parent doesn't just stop and wait?  I intend for them to exit at the same time, the parent sending a signal to the child.  Does that work?

Comment: If you only want them to exit at the same time, you just do what you do - `wait` in the parent, and make the child process to terminate by itself (when it is done doing whatever it is supposed to do). But if you need them to communicate something other than termination time, then you will have to add more stuff.

Comment: So it sounds like IPC between the two will not be viable because the parent cannot proceed until the child terminates?  Maybe I should run in the child on a separate thread to achieve that?

Comment: The parent does not arbitrarily or automatically wait for the child.  It only waits for the child when you *make* it do so, such as via  the `wait()` function.  I'm not really following where you are getting a different idea.

Comment: It sounded to me from comments by @Eugene Sh. that the parent calls fork-execv, then waits until the child process terminates.  My plan is for them to continue until the parent finishes and sends a signal to the child to terminate first.  The child should perform functions for the parent at intervals.  If the parent has to wait until the child is finished then that won't work as fork is a one-time deal.

Comment: EugeneSh only ever said that the parent `wait()`s for the child *when it is ready to do so*, and not before.

Comment: Then I should be able to use my IPC setup.  Now I understand.  You've both been very helpful.  Thank you again.

Comment: I just edited the C code above for fork-execv and removed the line "wait( &status ); }" but the program still performs as before.  It just hangs in the child.